# Proper way to establish persistent complex object in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am looking for the "good practice" advice on how to handle a persistent object in Flask.

I have my own classes that handle user, groups, user membership in groups and user/group permissions. Among those, there is a Passport class that holds information about the current user and their permissions.

The idea is that each user session should be associated with its own Passport object that persists over the views: so that certain permissions could be initialized upon user login, and can be checked later while using the views and performing AJAX requests.

Currently I have serialize and deserialize methods in the Passport class, and a FlaskPassport class that is initialized in the views.py global scope, that has a read-only "passport" property that reads the serialized passport data from a session variable and returns deserialized object. And it has a save() method that does the opposite. This FlaskPassport class also has a decorator method for views that checks the permissions. And the code that gives access to the passport data that are stored in the session in serialized state looks pretty clumsy. The fact that the passport object has to be manually saved after alteration doesn't seem right - it should be so that Flask saves the altered passport object to the session after the request is processed automatically.

So, I am looking for some clever pattern that would give access to a global passport object, accessible to all views, and also let me add decorators to the views that need permission checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, including:

1. Storing the `passport` instance on `g` and using a `before_request` and `after_request` handler pair to hydrate / serialize the instance from / to the session:

   ```
   @app.before_request
   def load_passport():
       if "passport_id" in session:
           g.passport = create_passport_from_id(session["passport_id"])

   @app.after_request
   def serialize_passport(response):
       if hasattr(g, "passport"):
           session["passport_id"] = g.passport.id
       return response
   ```
2. Use the thread-local pattern that Flask uses for `request` and `g` (among others).  Under the hood this uses Werkzeug's `LocalProxy`, which is mounted on either the application context or the request context (depending on the lifetime of the underlying object):

   ```
   from flask import (_request_ctx_stack as request_ctx,
                      has_request_context, session)
   from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy

   current_passport = LocalProxy(get_passport)

   def get_passport():
       if has_request_context() and "passport_id" in session:
           if not hasattr(request_ct.top, "passport"):
               passport_id = session["passport_id"]
               request_ctx.top.passport = construct_passport_from_id(passport_id)
            return getattr(request_ctx.top, "passport", None)
       return EmptyPassport()

   @app.after_request
   def serialize(response):
       if current_passport.is_not_empty():
           session["passport_id"] = current_passport.id
       return response
   ```

It is worth noting that I have chosen not to serialize the entire passport to the session, since that information is passed back and forth with every request (depending on how much information you are storing in your passport, this may or may not be something that concerns you).

It is also worth noting that neither of these approaches is inherently secure. Flask does sign the session cookie to make it tamper proof, but you'll still need to worry about logout, freshness, etc. Take a look at [Flask-Login's code](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/) for some of the other things you'll want to think about.